# How to combine a hidden/functional scrollbar with parallax elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have a problem with a parallax page.

- the scrollbar is hidden (by pushing it to the side with inner&outer divs and "right: -17px;")
- got some parallax div elements which should float over the page with different speed

The code for the hidden scrollbar separately works and also the code for the the parallax elements separately does work.

**My Problem:** I tried to combine these codes but only the **hidden scrollbar** works. I haven't figured out the problem ... Maybe the js code of the parallax cannot work with the "inner div" hidden scrollbar? The "inner div" have to be a kinda `<body>`. If I give the body a height of for example 3000px, then the parallax does work, but then I get a 2nd scrollbar.

I'd prefer to solve this without using 3rd party libraries.

```js
var elementOne = document.querySelector("#elementOne");
    var elementTwo = document.querySelector("#elementTwo");
    var elementThree = document.querySelector("#elementThree");

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el)
    {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrollLoop, false);

    var xScrollPosition;
    var yScrollPosition;

    function scrollLoop()
    {
      xScrollPosition = window.scrollX;
      yScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

      setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * -0.2, elementOne);
      setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * -1.5, elementTwo);
      setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * .5, elementThree);

      requestAnimationFrame(scrollLoop);
    }
```

```css
*
    {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    #outer
    {
   height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }
    #inner
    {
      top: 0px;
   right: -17px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
   position: absolute;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #frame_1
    {
      top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #22E1FF 0%, #1D8FE1 48%, #625EB1 100%);
    }
    #frame_2
    {
      top: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #D4FFEC 0%, #57F2CC 48%, #4596FB 100%);
    }
    #frame_3
    {
      top: 200%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #473B7B 0%, #3584A7 51%, #30D2BE 100%);
    }
    #elementOne
    {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      top: 150%;
      left: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 10;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #22E1FF 0%, #1D8FE1 48%, #625EB1 100%);
      opacity: .75;
    }
    #elementTwo
    {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      top: 350%;
      left: 55%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 8;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #D4FFEC 0%, #57F2CC 48%, #4596FB 100%);
      opacity: .75;
    }
    #elementThree
    {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 25%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 9;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #473B7B 0%, #3584A7 51%, #30D2BE 100%);
      opacity: .75;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>

      <body>

        <div id="outer">
          <div id="inner">

            <div id="frame_1"></div>
            <div id="frame_2"></div>
            <div id="frame_3"></div>

            <div id="elementOne"></div>
            <div id="elementTwo"></div>
            <div id="elementThree"></div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Will you at some point stop deleting and then re-asking this question, or …? I saw a version of this question yesterday, I saw one you posted four hours ago … and now here we have the next iteration. Please show some patience and give people a chance to react to your question, instead of doing the constant delete/re-post cycle to “cheat” your way up the queue again.

Comment: @misorude, questions are dead after few hours on this forum because of the amount of question which getting asked ... I can see it on the view counts. But this questions is very important for me, i'm researching while the question is up but it seems, If no javascript expert does see it in the first 4 hours or earlier, then they will never see it, because in the time there are thousands of new questions... sorry for the reposts

Comment: That doesn't excuse abusing the system - everyone here is volunteering their time to help, and there are many willing to. If you don't think your question is getting enough visibility, then try editing the question to make it clearer, including more specific tags, and being patient.

Comment: Yes, here are some really nice people which also helped me with other questions. You need sometimes a good timing, that the right people see your question and to increase the chance, i deleted the question and reposted it, I also changed the questions. Again, sorry for that. And good javascript devs are really hard to find, everyone is using the dawn jquery ...

Comment: See, this question is dead... the view counts do only increase with my own views ... :'D